# Android phone not displaying SMS sender ID

Tags: android, sms, sender-id

My Android phone does not show SMS sender ID, for example if one of the friends from my contact list, texts me, my phone will not show the name of the sender (which is saved in my contact list), it just shows the phone number of the sender. But when they call me, my phone shows the caller ID name (as saved in my contact list). Any help fixing this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions only. Also, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068.

Answer (score 0):

```
See if your App has necessary permission
```

**Or**

```
Delete the App data/ reinstall it
```

**Or**

```
Try some other messaging app
```

**Or**

```
Reset your phone
```

Comment: I did restart my phone, it did not help. The SMS is the default SMS on my phone, I can't uninstall it.

Comment: All other apps (which work by internet, like Whatsapp) work fine

Comment: @Ebi Checked the permissions?

Comment: I just checked the permissions (for contacts and SMS). They are OK

Comment: @Ebi Long press the app, then there should be option like setting or otherwise go to your Phone setting -> Apps -> System App Setting -> search for the messanging app .

Comment: @ Suryansh I did confirm permissions are given to the app. But the problem still exists.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it. In settings, search for Sync (google contact sync), enable it. That will fix the problem.